# Excel Range to PowerPoint - Paste Problems

Tags: excel, vba, format, powerpoint, paste

Im having some issues when pasting a Range from Excel to PowerPoint. I want to keep it as  Keepsource format:

```
Function copyToPPT()

'Create an instance of PowerPoint.
Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
' Create a PowerPoint presentation.
nomeppt = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\" + "SR-1871_R1 - ID-033 - Bi-Weekly LATAM QC Communication Meeting - data_Blank.pptx"

With pptApp
    Let .Visible = True
    Let .WindowState = 3
    Set Pres1 = pptApp.Presentations.Open(nomeppt)
End With


i = 8
While i <= 14
    slide = "Slide " & i & " Final"
    Workbooks("Results.xlsx").Activate
    Worksheets(slide).Activate
    Worksheets(slide).Range("A1").Select
    Worksheets(slide).Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Worksheets(slide).Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select 'Selecionando os registros - Simulando ctrl + shift baixo/direta
    Selection.Copy
    pptApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide Index:=i
    'pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=7 - NOT THE FORMAT I WANT
    i = i + 1
    pptApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting") 'freeze the powerpoint when pasting...
    pptApp.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus

Wend

End Function
```

Comment: OP needs 2 more upvotes for being able to chat. If anyone can help then please do :)

Comment: Try www.pptxbuilder.com. It automatically converts excel data to powerpoint charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
pptApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault
```

This give the same result as

```
pptApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
```

Value of `ppPasteDefault` is `0` So you can either put

```
Const ppPasteDefault as Integer = 0
```

at the top of your code or use

```
pptApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=0
```

**EDIT (Followup from comments)**

I have changed your code. Use this and tell me if you get any error. This doesn't use `.Activate/.Select` [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Try this

```
Sub copyToPPT()
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim LastCol As String
    Dim rng As Range

    'Create an instance of PowerPoint.
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    ' Create a PowerPoint presentation.
    nomeppt = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
    "SR-1871_R1 - ID-033 - Bi-Weekly LATAM QC Communication Meeting - data_Blank.pptx"

    With pptApp
        .Visible = True
        .WindowState = 3
        Set Pres1 = pptApp.Presentations.Open(nomeppt)
    End With

    i = 8

    While i <= 14
        slide = "Slide " & i & " Final"
        With Workbooks("Results.xlsx").Worksheets(slide)
            lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            lCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            LastCol = Split(.Cells(, lCol).Address, "$")(1)

            Set rng = .Range("A1:" & LastCol & lRow)
        End With

        pptApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide Index:=i

        rng.Copy

        DoEvents

        pptApp.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate

        pptApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")

        Wait 3

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tested and tried the code and it works... Are you doing any other thing between copying and pasting? which may be clearing the clipboard. Alternatively add `DoEvents` after the copy command so that Excel gets enough time to place the image in the clipboard.

Comment: Put `DoEvents` after `Selection.Copy`

Comment: One moment, I am re-writing your entire function.. gimme 10 mins

Comment: One quick question. Does Row1 in Excel sheet have headers?

Comment: Updated. Please test it for me.

Comment: I created this room for you http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43055/jefferson-neves see if you can join me there?

Comment: ok in the mean time do this for me... Add this line `msgbox rng.address` before `rng.Copy` line and tell me what do you get before the error?

Comment: Hehehe. I got the Range: $A$1:$k$11 thats exactly the range that i need to paste. What i tried is, after the error, i manually pressed ctrl + v and its pasted the table normally. The problem is in the paste vba command.

Comment: cant test it now but can you replace the paste line with this? `pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0`

Comment: Still the same error, that's annoying! :). Shapes.PasteSpecial: Invalid Request. clipboard is empty (NO IT's NOT!) or contains data  which may not be pasted here.

Comment: Ok.. One more test.. Updating my code.. see if it helps... 2 mins

Comment: Try it now. You will have to refresh the page

Comment: Since your query is solved, Can you delete the comment from above so that it looks less cluttered